# how can I customize a scope generator in xtext to cross reference variables from a file

Tags: parsing, scope, xtext, eclipse-emf, xtend

Please refer to the Expressions Grammar and code generator present in below link

[Is there some way to test my grammar which refer to EAttributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750445/is-there-some-way-to-test-my-grammar-which-refer-to-eattributes)

What I want to do is create a file (.ecore) and save it locally, specifically for the purpose of storing variables and i want my code to cross references the variables of EAttribute type from that ".ecore" file. This is in context with the below rule of grammar.

```
Atomic returns Expression:
...
    {VariableRef} variable=[ecore::EAttribute|QualifiedName];
```

I am unable to find much help on how to customize a global scope provider as per this requirement. Would really appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: can you give details WHAT you want to customize?

Comment: i want some customization so that i can only use EAttributes present in a "test.ecore" file which i have save locally. i don't want to cross refer to any other eAttributes that might be present there. Please note that i have hardcoded all the eAttributes in "test.ecore" file. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: have a look at the filteringscope. in your scopeprovider you can call super.getScope respectively delegateGetScope and wrap this into a filteringScope